# Is it possible to provide a function name as an initializer in another function's definition?

Tags: c

We can provide an object as an initializer in another object's definition. It just copies and assigns the value of an object to another.

Is it possible to provide a function name as an initializer in another function's definition?

Where does the C standard say if it is allowed or not? I didn't find it, so I suppose it is possible.

The following two examples will result in syntax error:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int f(){};

int main()
{
    int (g=f)();
    int h() = f;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Variables can be initialized. What purpose should it have to initialize a function? Or assign a value to a function? Do you mean function pointers?

Comment: You cannot initialize or assign a function. You can initialize a function pointer but the syntax is not like that. Try `int (*g)() = f;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably want a function pointer (as a function doesn't really make sense in this context):

```
int (*h)() = f;
```

Answer (score 1):

No. Function declarations can't have an initializer.
If you want to ensure type compatibility, you can use a function `typedef`.

```
typedef int f_tp(void);
f_tp f, h; //check f and h for compatibility with int (*)(void)
int f(){}  //✓

//will get an error here because h was declared f_tp h == int h(void);
void h()
{
}
```